# Add two or more form values to get a grand total

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript function works independently for each line in the php foreach loop below just fine. However I Want to add those 
two independent totals together to get a grand total and display it in the DIV tag below. I can't figure out how to set aside the 
amounts and then add them together. The grand total should update with each change of quanity just like the amounts currently do.
Right now totalprice just reflects one amount but not a grand total.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function update(iteration){


var qty = document.getElementById('qty_' + iteration).value;
// alert('quantity_' + iteration);

var price = document.getElementById('price_' + iteration).value;
price = price.substring(0, 7);
qty = parseInt(qty);

var amount = (qty * price).toFixed(2) ;
parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount_' + iteration).value = amount).toFixed(2);


//HERE's the code that's not working..
var subtotal;
for(var i =1; i < itemCount; i++) {
subtotal += document.getElementById('amount_' + i).value;
}


//this works
var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
divobj.style.display='block';
divobj.innerHTML = "Total $"+parseFloat(subtotal);

}
</script>
</head>


<?php

$listitems = unserialize($row["products"]);
    $i=1; 
        foreach($listitems as $item)
        {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$item["code"].'</td><td><input type="number" id="qty_'.$i.'" name="qty_'.$i.'"  min="1" size="3" value="1" onChange="iteration = '.$i.'; update(iteration); " /></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="price_'.$i.'" id="price_'.$i.'"  value="';
        echo $item['price'];
        echo '" />';
        echo $item['price'];
        echo '</td><td><input type="text" name="amount_'.$i.'" id="amount_'.$i.'" size="6" readonly value="';
        echo $item['price'];
        echo '"/></td></tr>';
    $i++;
    }


?>


<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

Comment: You tell javascript to parseFloat(subtotal), but before that line, I don't see any definition of "subtotal" (In fact, that line is the definition). You may be trying to do parseFloat() of an undefined variable, and then, it fails.

Comment: You seem to be trying to calculate a number by adding to itself before it exists.

Comment: Can someone explain what the parseFloat is actually doing with the document.getElement = amount?

Comment: parseFloat should turn a string into a number, from what I think I read.

Comment: @AllenHarris I get that you want a number, but are you setting a document.value in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things stick out.

[parseInt( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) needs a radix parameter.

`parseInt(qty, 10);`

Im confused on what this line is doing:
`parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount_' + iteration).value = amount).toFixed(2);`

parseFloat returns a floating point, but you arent setting it to anything?

The problem that is causing your error is the `var subtotal` declaration.

You are declaring a variable to equal `amount + itself`, which doesn't exist yet.
What do you want subtotal to equal?

Edit:
Now that you updated, you want to iterate the number of items and add them all together.

```
var subtotal;
for(var i =0; i < itemCount; i++) {
  subtotal += document.getElementById('amount_' + i).value;
}
```

This would iterate over 0-itemCount of the amount elements.

Comment: in the php code below, it lists items in a shopping cart. each line has its own subtotal. I want to add the totals together and show it in the DIV tag at the end.

Comment: So what is the equation for subtotal? var subtotal = amount + ?

Comment: I've updated the line above that's not working..It works great now, but it's hard coded. I need it to dynamically work based on an infinite number of items in the cart.

Comment: infinite number of items, so amount1 + amount2 + ... to itemTotal?

Comment: I'll update the code above with yours.. but it didn't work. The result was blank. amount_ will start with amount_1 as it echos out, so I set i=1 in the script you wrote. still nothing.

Comment: Because itemCount isnt a thing, you need to pass that in.

Comment: If I take out the word itemCount and replace it with a number like 5, it still doesn't work for me.